# QML component isn't displayed if it was created programmatically from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

My goal is to create a custom Component (lets call it `ComponentLoader`) which can instantiate another component (lets call it `DelegateComponent`) via delegate.

The problem is that the instance of `DelegateComponent` isn't displayed after is was created (white screen). Note: `tst_component is loaded` message IS present which means that `DelegateComponent` instance was actually created.

Here is a minimal example:

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: tst_component

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.debug("tst_component is loaded");
            }

            Label {
                text: "hello world"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

// doesn't work
    ComponentLoader {
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: tst_component
    }

// works
//    Loader {
//        anchors.fill: parent
//        sourceComponent: tst_component
//    }
}
```

componentloader.h + componentloader.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <QQuickItem>

class ComponentLoader : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlComponent* delegate READ delegate WRITE setDelegate NOTIFY delegateChanged)

public:
    QQmlComponent* delegate() const;
    void setDelegate(QQmlComponent*);

signals:
    void delegateChanged();

private:
    void generate();

protected:
    void componentComplete() override;

private:
    QQmlComponent* mDelegate = nullptr;
};

// componentloader.cpp
#include "componentloader.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QtQmlModels/QtQmlModels>
#include <QQuickWindow>

QQmlComponent* ComponentLoader::delegate() const
{
    return mDelegate;
}

void ComponentLoader::setDelegate(QQmlComponent* delegate)
{
    if (delegate != mDelegate)
    {
        mDelegate = delegate;
        emit delegateChanged();
    }
}

void ComponentLoader::componentComplete()
{
    QQuickItem::componentComplete();
    generate();
}

void ComponentLoader::generate()
{
    QQmlEngine* engine = qmlEngine(this);
    QQmlContext* root_ctx = engine->rootContext();
    QQmlContext* ctx = new QQmlContext(root_ctx);

    QObject* item = mDelegate->create(ctx);
    QQuickItem* quickItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(item);

    QQuickItem* quickParent = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(parent());
    quickItem->setParent(quickParent);
    quickItem->setParentItem(quickParent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `quickParent` pointer is taking the QObject parent() value instead of the QQuickItem parentItem() value.

Simply changing it to this worked for me when I tried your code:

```
QQuickItem* quickParent = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(parentItem());
```

I also don't think you need to call setParent() at all. Just setParentItem().